# Was a scene in "Alien: Covenant" inspired by the death island painting of Böcklin?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-covenant

In the movie *Alien: Covenant* there’s a shot of a dramatically illuminated rock on which tall, thin, poplar-like trees grow.

I took a picture of the scene. The movie was on TV tonight. When I saw the scene I immediately saw the connection. I love that painting. My girlfriend threw up her arms in despair.

[image: scene from Alien: Covenant]

The painting *Death Island* by Böcklin is almost identical to the imagery used in that scene (or vice-versa):

[image: Death Island, by Böckling]

Is this just coincidence? I can't imagine it is, and Death Island fits the movie rather nicely. It’s a great movie.

Comment: You had me right up until your last sentence.

Comment: Arnold Böcklin created several versions of this popular painting, and it has inspired *many* other works. (Incidentally, Hitler acquired the 3rd version in 1933). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isle_of_the_Dead_(painting) "The tiny islet is dominated by a dense grove of tall, dark cypress trees—associated by long-standing tradition with cemeteries and mourning"

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Concept Artist Wayne Haag (with the assistance of Steve Messing) intentionally referenced this painting at the request of Ridley Scott.

> **WH:** *There's a definite influence from ... I think I mentioned Böcklin. We referenced Arnold Böcklin a lot.*
>
> **AVPForum:** *The 'Isle of the Dead', is it?*
>
> **WH:** *Right. So there's a look and a feel to Böcklin's paintings, and that's what Ridley's aiming at. It's not so much the detail, necessarily, although he's big on trees. Oh he loved the trees.... but there's a general overall look and feel to his paintings that we were riffing off.*
>
> <sub><sup>[AvPGalaxy Interviews Wayne Haag, Alien: Covenant Concept Artist – AvPGalaxy Podcast #42/ - Timecode 38:55](https://www.avpgalaxy.net/2016/11/14/avpgalaxy-interviews-wayne-haag-alien-covenant-concept-artist/)</sup></sub>

You can see an original concept shot below, from Messing's [Artstation catalogue](https://www.artstation.com/artwork/mw2qe);

[image]

Interestingly, H.R. Giger (one of the original concept artists for Alien and whose work has been referenced throughout the series of films) also did a couple of different versions of this painting in 1977, which Ridley Scott would no doubt have seen.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thats the scene indeed! Was it used as inspiration? Would be very appropriate, I liked the movie a lot. Though the reviews were mixed. Rating from 8 to 2...Ah. Yes!

Comment: Is it because David loving death or all the frozen dead bodies? Which would make the film even greater.

Comment: The first painting in the link is beatifull!

Comment: Note for future: Ridley Scott is as much an artist / creative as he is a film maker and he never does anything randomly. Graphic Designers / Illustrators (like painters) always reference something in their work, partly inspiration, partly its a game or a nod to someone else... like Clapton dropping in a Stevie Ray Vaughn riff to a live song - its not an accident.